# Is my PyCrypto implementation secure for my purposes?

Tags: encryption, python-2.7, aes, pycrypto

I'm not experienced with programming, and the PyCrypto documentation is pretty sparse for a beginner. Let's say that I encrypt a file with the code I have written below, and send it over the internet. What I'm concerned about is the security of the file between computers A and B. Let's assume that the computers themselves are secure and the key is transported securely. Have I implemented things correctly? Anything else I should know about? Using Python 2.7 and PyCrypto 2.6

Thank you in advance for any answer.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

def get_random(length):
    r = Random.new().read(length)
    return r

def aes_encrypt(key, file_in, file_out):
    data_source = open(file_in, 'rb')
    data = data_source.read()
    data_source.close()
    iv = get_random(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    data_encrypted = iv+cipher.encrypt(data)
    file_encrypted = open(file_out, 'wb')
    file_encrypted.write(data_encrypted)
    file_encrypted.close()

def aes_decrypt(key, file_in, file_out):
    data_source = open(file_in, 'rb')
    data = data_source.read()
    data_source.close()
    iv = data[:AES.block_size]
    data = data[AES.block_size:]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    data_decrypted = cipher.decrypt(data)
    file_decrypted = open(file_out, 'wb')
    file_decrypted.write(data_decrypted)
    file_decrypted.close()

#testing
key = get_random(32)
#encrypting the file on computer A
aes_encrypt(key, 'file.dat', 'file.enc')
#decrypting the file on computer B
aes_decrypt(key, 'file.enc', 'file.dat')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing one of the most important considerations in implementing crypto, which is message integrity. Unfortunately just encrypting a message isn't enough to ensure it isn't tampered with, especially in the case of streaming modes like CTR, CFB, and OFB.

It looks like you are using CFB mode (MODE_CFB). The way this works is a random keystream is generated with AES, and the result is XOR-ed against the plaintext. This means that if someone flips a bit in the ciphertext, the corresponding bit will flip in the decrypted plaintext. An attacker could alter your message to mean something entirely different, and there'd be no way for you to detect it. For reference of how CFB mode (decryption) works:

[image: CFB Mode]

If I flip the first bit of the first block of the ciphertext, it'll flip the first bit of the first block of the decrypted plaintext.

You need to either apply an [HMAC](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/) or use [AES-GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) mode, which will handle confidentiality and integrity together.

There are better mode choices than CFB, so if there's no strong reason for preferring it, I would recommend AES-GCM first, then AES-CTR with HMAC second.